# Print a text if a view result is equal to a certain value

Tags: views, theming

In a template file, how can I use PHP to print some text if a view has a certain value?

The view uses the node ID, so I guess this argument needs to be passed to the view (as it would be if the view was embedded onto the page).

Here is my attempt:

```
<?php
  $view = views_get_view('hide_weight_2');
  if ($view->execute_display('default', $args) == 'Yes' ):
?>
  <h1>Result of view was yes</h1>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand well your question, I guess that you can make this in a rough way from a template View. Inside this template file you can add the respective conditional to show your text.

Here is the part of views-view-unformatted.tpl.php when each result is printed:

```
<?php foreach ($rows as $id => $row): ?>
  <div class="<?php print $classes[$id]; ?>">   
    <?php print $row; ?>
  </div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Then, you can parse `$row` to catch the respective value and print a message. You can use [preg_match()](http://php.net/manual/es/function.preg-match.php) to match the value For example, instead of `<?php print $row; ?>` you could use:

```
<?php
  if (preg_match("/(here text to match)/i", $row)) {
    print "Aha!:" . $row;
  }
  else {
    print $row;
  }
?>
```

I guess you can improve this seeking per target fields.